# bash: export: 'PATH.....': not a valid identifier message every time i open bash

Tags: windows, bash, terminal

I'm using Git Bash on windows 10 and every time I open it I'm getting a long message starting with "bash: export: `PATH-/c/Users/..." lists a ton of folders and then ends with "not a valid identifier".
I uninstalled an reinstalled the bash but it still appears. This started happening after I installed python and was trying to configure it. Python works now and everything works fine but I just want to get rid of the message.

Comment: Does it say `PATH-` or `PATH=`?

Comment: Although this is about Bash on Windows, the answers from over in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79658/ apply as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if there's a `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file somewhere in your home folder. If you can locate that, open that with your editor of choice and try replacing the line `export PATH-/c/Users/...` with `export PATH=/c/Users/...`

It would usually be in your home folder: `C:\Users\<your user name>`.
Typing `echo ${HOME}` in the git bash terminal will tell you where your home folder is located.

Comment: if not `.bashrc`, then also check for .bash_profile`.

Comment: @Paul Hodges That's a very good point, thanks for noting that!

Comment: If not `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` then also check for `.profile`.